# Accessing Class Variables by enum

Tags: swift, enums

I have following code which basically defines enum for different companies and different methods for each company.

```
protocol Fetcher {
    func getDetail()
    static var idRegex:String {get}
}
class FooFetcher:Fetcher {
    static var idRegex = "(^\\d{5}$)"
    var company = Company.Foo

    init (name:String?, id:String) {
        println("Name: \(name) id: \(id)")
    }

    func getDetail() {
        println("Foo Get detail")
    }
}

class BarFetcher:Fetcher {
    static var idRegex = "(^\\d{11}$)"
    var company = Company.Bar

    init (name:String?, id:String) {
        println("Name: \(name) id: \(id)")
    }

    func getDetail() {
        println("Bar Get detail")
    }
}

enum Company:Int {
    case Foo
    case Bar

    func fetcher(name:String?, id:String) -> AnyObject {
        switch self {
        case Foo:
            return FooFetcher(name: name, id: id)
        case .Bar:
            return BarFetcher(name: name, id: id)
        }
    }

}

var compList = [Company.Foo , Company.Bar]
```

How can I get idRegex by using compList array only? I don't want to create another array like `[FooFetcher.idRegex,BarFetcher.idRegex]` because it will bloat the file. I want to use enum because it is easy to store their rawValue with Core Data.

I also wonder how to write better fetcher function for `Company` enum. Currently I use fetcher function like below

```
var company = Company.Foo
var strategy = company.fetcher("Some name", id: "Some id") as! Fetcher
strategy.getDetail()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two responses both provide good contributions. For example, returning a Fetcher rather than AnyObject makes complete sense, as does a regex() function. The thing that I query, however, is whether you could use enums with associated values rather than this enum + class approach, but putting that to one side and answering the question in hand if you really want to directly access the .idRegex from an instance then it needs to be a regular instance variable not a class variable. One way to have it both ways is to return the type variable through an instance variable like so:

```
protocol Fetcher {
    func getDetail()
    var idRegex:String {get}
    static var regex:String {get}
}
class FooFetcher:Fetcher {
    static var regex = "(^\\d{5}$)"
    var idRegex:String { return FooFetcher.regex }
    var company = Company.Foo

    init (name:String?, id:String) {
        println("Name: \(name) id: \(id)")
    }

    func getDetail() {
        println("Foo Get detail")
    }
}

class BarFetcher:Fetcher {
    static var regex = "(^\\d{11}$)"
    var idRegex:String { return BarFetcher.regex }
    var company = Company.Bar

    init (name:String?, id:String) {
        println("Name: \(name) id: \(id)")
    }

    func getDetail() {
        println("Bar Get detail")
    }
}

enum Company:Int {
    case Foo
    case Bar

    func fetcher(name:String?, id:String) -> Fetcher {
        switch self {
        case Foo:
            return FooFetcher(name: name, id: id)
        case .Bar:
            return BarFetcher(name: name, id: id)
        }
    }

}

var compList = [Company.Foo, Company.Bar]
var company = Company.Foo
var strategy = company.fetcher("Some name", id: "Some id")
strategy.getDetail()
strategy.idRegex
```

**Edit Responding to Query**

If you want the fetcher to not necessarily initialize an instance then set whatever requirement there is to determine whether a value or nil is returned.

```
enum Company:Int {
    case Foo
    case Bar

    func fetcher(name:String?, id:String) -> Fetcher? {
        switch self {
        case Foo:
            if FooFetcher.regex == "(^\\d{11}$)" {
                return FooFetcher(name: name, id: id)}
            else {return nil}
        case .Bar:
            if BarFetcher.regex == "(^\\d{11}$)" {
                return BarFetcher(name: name, id: id)
            }
            else {return nil}
        }
    }

}

var compList = [Company.Foo, Company.Bar]
var company = Company.Foo
var strategy = company.fetcher("Some name", id: "Some id")
strategy?.getDetail()
strategy?.idRegex
```

Comment: Thanks again for your detailed explanation. My problem is I want to initialize and use company.fetcher IF idRegex fits the criteria. I don't want to initialize the fetcher class just to check its idRegex property. I guess what I am asking is impossible or doesn't make a sense in terms of Swift language. If there was a way to associate enum with class type so that I can get its value or call its method it would be wonderful. I tried var classType:AnyObject {
        switch self {
        case .Foo:
            return FooFetcher.self etc but it didn't work.

Comment: why don't you return an optional from fetcher()? See edit above.

Comment: Thanks I guess this is the best way until proven otherwise. I appreciate the time you spent to help me. Best regards

Answer (score 1):

`AnyObject` does not support `Fetcher`, in the `company.fetcher` function instead of returning `AnyObject` is `-> Fetcher`

```
enum Company:Int {
    case Foo
    case Bar

    func fetcher(name:String?, id:String) -> Fetcher {
        switch self {
        case .Foo:
            return FooFetcher(name: name, id: id)
        case .Bar:
            return BarFetcher(name: name, id: id)
        }
    }

}
```

`FOO` also there corresponds almost `.foo`

Comment: Thanks for your response but my problem is not the fetcher function. Adding Fetcher is just syntactic sugar. My problem is how to get  ```idRegex``` from ```Company```.

Comment: Price Ringo replied to his request, adding a better face clean syntax in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Along with eliasRuizHz's answer, add a new `regex` method to the `Company` enum.

```
func regex() -> String {
    switch self {
    case .Foo:
        return FooFetcher.idRegex
    case .Bar:
        return BarFetcher.idRegex
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have more than 50 companies. Using your approach, will bloat the code which I am trying to avoid. It is same as defining another array. Or you can just use a dictionary with key as company and value as idregex but I am trying to find some shorter version which is error prone. Sorry for being nitpicky.

Comment: Nitpicky is good. However you fundamentally need to associate an Int (enum rawValue) with a Class first. That is hard to do without a switch statement. It is up to you to judge the trade offs. Having a single source of truth is usually better than duplicate, hard coded data structures.